# How to add Javascript addEventListener on window scroll

Tags: javascript, velocity

So, I have a nav that when I hover the icon, shows/hide, which is working great! Now, I want to hide the menu when the user scrolls down the widown, then the show/hide on hover functionality takes place again. Below is my working code:

```
byClass('nav-toggle')[0].addEventListener('mouseover', showNav);
byClass('nav-wrap')[0].addEventListener('mouseleave', hideNav);
```

I try to add something like this:

```
  byClass('nav-wrap')[0].addEventListener('scroll', hideNav);
```

.. but it didn't work. I guess its because I have to specify that I want to hide when the "window" is scrolled down?

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: you have to add `scroll` event to `window`, as in `window.addEventListener('scroll'`

Comment: How it would look the whole string of code if you dont mind?

Comment: see my answer for details

Comment: did my answer help?

Comment: I didnt work.. but I will try again tomorrow! Thank you! The main.js file was minify, but they did have a copy of unminify on the server, but once I use that one, it gets broken. Any ideas?

Comment: no problem. regarding your second question, this seems like a separate question and need its own question thread

Comment: so how did it go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to listen for `scroll` start and hide the nav. And you also have to know when user stops scrolling. There is no separate event for that, so we can use `timeout` to show your nav in 150 ms if the scroll has finished.

```
var timer = null;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if(timer !== null) {
        clearTimeout(timer);        
    } else {
        hideNav();
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
          showNav();
        }, 150);
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample to hide menu on scroll

```js
var content = document.getElementById('two');

content.addEventListener('scroll', hideMenu);


function hideMenu()
{
    var menu = document.getElementById('one');
    menu.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
section {
    width: 80%;
    height: 200px;
    background: aqua;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
div#one {
    width: 15%;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
}
div#two {
    height: 200px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"> SCROLL TO HIDE MENU<br> shows/hide, which is working great! Now, I want to hide the menu when the user scrolls down the widown, then the show/hide on hover functionality takes place again. Below is my working code:

byClass('nav-toggle')[0].addEventListener('mouseover', showNav);
byClass('nav-wrap')[0].addEventListener('mouseleave', hideNav);
I try to add something like this:

  byClass('nav-wrap')[0].addEventListener('scroll', hideNav);
.. but it didn't work. I guess its because I have to specify that I want to hide when the "window" is scrolled down?

Any help would be very appreciated.So, I have a nav that when I hover the icon, shows/hide, which is working great! Now, I want to hide the menu when the user scrolls down the widown, then the show/hide on hover functionality takes place again. Below is my working code:

byClass('nav-toggle')[0].addEventListener('mouseover', showNav);
byClass('nav-wrap')[0].addEventListener('mouseleave', hideNav);
I try to add something like this:

  byClass('nav-wrap')[0].addEventListener('scroll', hideNav);
.. but it didn't work. I guess its because I have to specify that I want to hide when the "window" is scrolled down?

Any help would be very appreciated.So, I have a nav that when I hover the icon, shows/hide, which is working great! Now, I want to hide the menu when the user scrolls down the widown, then the show/hide on hover functionality takes place again. Below is my working code:

byClass('nav-toggle')[0].addEventListener('mouseover', showNav);
byClass('nav-wrap')[0].addEventListener('mouseleave', hideNav);
I try to add something like this:

  byClass('nav-wrap')[0].addEventListener('scroll', hideNav);
.. but it didn't work. I guess its because I have to specify that I want to hide when the "window" is scrolled down?

Any help would be very appreciated.So, I have a nav that when I hover the icon, shows/hide, which is working great! Now, I want to hide the menu when the user scrolls down the widown, then the show/hide on hover functionality takes place again. Below is my working code:

byClass('nav-toggle')[0].addEventListener('mouseover', showNav);
byClass('nav-wrap')[0].addEventListener('mouseleave', hideNav);
I try to add something like this:

  byClass('nav-wrap')[0].addEventListener('scroll', hideNav);
.. but it didn't work. I guess its because I have to specify that I want to hide when the "window" is scrolled down?

Any help would be very appreciated.</div>
</section>
```